# Does Hyper-V on Windows 10 Professional have the same features as Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, virtualization

Is Hyper-V bundled with Windows 10 the same for running guest operation systems as the one foudn in Windows Server 2016? or does Hyper-V on Windows Server have additional features / wider upper limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features included in Hyper-V on Windows Server that are not included in Hyper-V on Windows:

> - Virtualizing GPUs using RemoteFX
> - Live migration of virtual machines from one host to another
> - Hyper-V Replica
> - Virtual Fiber Channel
> - SR-IOV networking
> - Shared .VHDX

[Review original reference on Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/)